# zurb-foundation javascripts are not working 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

Javascripts are not working. Am i missing something ? I can see that javascript and css files are in the generated html. Thanks.

gemfile

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'compass-rails', '~> 1.0.3'
  gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 3.0.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .
```

application.css.scss

```
@import "foundation";
```

generated code

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/modernizr.foundation.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/jquery.customforms.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/jquery.orbit-1.4.0.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/jquery.placeholder.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/jquery.reveal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/jquery.tooltips.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/index.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/site.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the same problem I was having, it's because the foundation `app.js` file isn't included by default.

I'm not sure why, since it really seems like it should be, but try adding `//= require foundation/app` to your application.js and see if that fixes it.